# Nhibernate mapping accountability pattern

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, design-patterns

I am implementing the Fowler's Accountability Pattern.  I have Party with subclasses User, and PeopleGroup.  I have Accountability and AccountabilityType.  I have Party mapped as a table and User and PeopleGroup both mapped as separate tables.  Then lastly there's an Accountability_Party cross reference table.

So this all works fine, however, here's the problem.
If I get a peoplegroup and say

```
pg.ChildAccountablities.Where(x=>x.PartyType == "User")
```

thus getting all the Parties that are of type User, I can not then cast the Party to a User.  This I guess is upcasting.

The reason I need to do this is because I'm using a permissioning system that has an interface on User (IUser) to identify it.  I would like to say get all the users assigned to this peoplegroup and give them this permission. But the permissioning system interface requires a class with the IUser interface on it for the assignment and of course Party does not have that
Perhaps I could say something like

```
_repository.Query<User>(x=>x.ParentAccountabilities.Any(y=>y.Parent == myPeopleGroup))
```

but that seems like kind of a roundabout way of doing it.

Any thoughts or insights into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Raif

**Update**

here is a link to the [accountability pattern](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accountability.pdf) by Fowler .

Also the code or rather the mappings are as follows

```
public class PartyMap : DomainEntityMap<Party>
{
    public PartyMap()
    {
        HasManyToMany(x =>x.ParentAccountabilities).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore).LazyLoad();
        HasManyToMany(x =>x.ChildAccountabilities).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore).LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class PeopleGroupMap : SubclassMap<PeopleGroup>
{
    public PeopleGroupMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}

public class UserMap : SubclassMap<User>
    {
        public UserLoginInfoMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.LoginName);
            Map(x => x.Password);
            blah blah blah
        }
    }

public class AccountabilityMap : DomainEntityMap<Accountability>
{
    public AccountabilityMap()
    {
        References(x => x.Parent);
        References(x => x.Child);
        References(x => x.AccountabilityType);
    }
}

public class AccountabilityTypeMap : DomainEntityMap<AccountabilityType>
{
    public AccountabilityTypeMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

The DomaineEntityMap is just a map of DomainEntity from which all entities inherit and which has some basic stuff like created date modified date etc.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code for Accountability would help but i guess it has a Reference to Party which is lazyloaded. NH then creates a proxy deriving from party to represent the lazyloaded party instance. possible solutions

1. disable lazy loading of the Party reference
2. change the reference to referenceany(FluentMapping)/any(hbm mapping)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not sure if eager loading would allow me to upcast would it?  Secondly ReferencesAny is new to me but from what I'm reading it looks pretty freakin great.  I will try that later today.  I"d have to refactor the party object into an interface and get rid of party but that's fine I'd rather do it that way anyways.

Comment: eager loading would allow upcasting because there is no proxy which can't be upcastet. ReferenceAny is meant for Interfaces **and** Baseclasses, you don't need to refactor